# Error while defining sampling algorithm in hyper parameter tuning using random sampling - Version V1

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to perform the random sampling to accomplish the hyper parameter tuning and tuning parameter version 1 (v1). I would like to get the chance to define the algorithm as sampling algorithm explicitly.

Currently using the below code block and is there any chance of implementing explicitly defining sampling in V1? If not, any specific procedure to solve the issue is helpful.

```
from azureml.train.hyperdrive import RandomParameterSampling
from azureml.train.hyperdrive import normal, uniform, choice
param_sampling = RandomParameterSampling( {
        "learning_rate": normal(10, 3),
        "keep_probability": uniform(0.05, 0.1),
        "batch_size": choice(16, 32, 64, 128)
    }
)
```

Comment: can you please define the actual problem? It was mentioned as error in title and not mentioned any kind of error. Kindly change the title. It is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explicit procedure called a **sweep job**. This sweep job in **hyperparameter value**. We can mention the random sampling using the sweep job explicitly.

From azure.ai.ml.sweep import Normal, Uniform, RandomParameterSampling

```
Command_job_for_sweep = command_job(
    learning_rate = Normal(mu=value, sigma=value),
    keep_probability=Uniform(min_value= your value, max_value= value),
    batch_size = Choice(value=[.your values in list]),
)

Sweep_job = command_job_sweep.sweep(
    Computer =”cluster”,
    sampling_algorithm=”random”,
    ....
)
```

This will be available in **version 2 (v2)** of hyperparameter tuning in random sampling.